# Avoiding recursive alias on reload

Tags: ruby, alias, reload

Sometimes, we replace a method with a modified one by using `alias` like this:

```
alias old_foo :foo
private :old_foo
def foo
  ...
  old_foo
  ...
end
```

It is okay if it is ensured that such file is only loaded once, but in some cases, it can happen that such file is loaded more than once. Ordinary method definitions are okay in such cases: they will be overwritten by the same thing. And, variables are also okay (although they may emit warning messages). But for alias-ing, this situation cause a huge mess and infinite loop. What is the safest way to do alias in cases like the above so that it will not get messed up when the file is loaded more than once?

Comment: using `require` instead of `load` should ensure the "load only once" semantic.

Comment: Also, what about `if defined? old_foo`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Regarding your first comment, that is not a solution. I need to reload the file, and still not have problem. Regarding your second comment, that is the line of an answer I am asking. I have seen something like that, but wanted to discuss some variants. Whether I should use `defined?`, `respond_to?`, etc. Why to choose one over the other etc.

Comment: You should try it, seems like it'll work for you.